# Sandbox a make install command

Tags: package-management, linux

Is there a way to list all copied files while "make install" command issued?

I need them to create a list of files to be rsync'ed to another servers..

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the Makefile. If it's the standard one created with `automake` you can run:

`make install DESTDIR=/tmp/stage`

and all your files will end up under `/tmp/stage`. You can then rsync them to wherever you need.

Or better yet create a proper package (rpm, deb, ..) that you can install with your default tools. It's a bit more involved but leads to a lot more organised system.